# R .eps export and import into Word 2010

Tags: r, ms-word, eps

I would like to know how I can open .eps files from R in the word 2010. Here is an example of my plot.

```
postscript("FIG1.eps", height = 6, width = 6, horizontal = FALSE, paper = "special")
plot(c(140,220),c(5,75),type="n",xaxt="n",cex.axis=1,cex.lab=1.2,font=2,font.lab=2,las=1)
lines(c(145,170,200),c(7,60,66),lwd=2,lty=3,type="o",pch=5)
dev.off()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[R eps export and import into Word 2010](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12747916/r-eps-export-and-import-into-word-2010)
Problem solved by Marco Sandri with exporting .eps files from R and importing into Word 2010 on Windows using the colormodel="rgb" option (defaults to "srgb") of the postscript command. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Do this

Insert -> Picture -> select Encapsulated PostScript.

Done.

[image]

Comment: I did it but it does not work on my word. Just error of it is not possible to show the picture